# Seeking a comparison of Jewish and America law

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, halacha-theory

There are at least several questions on this site about comparisons of Jewish and American law (samples below). I seek an article or book that compares Jewish and America law (where they overlap).
Somewhat similar questions on MY: 
[Is there "פה שאסר הוא פה שהתיר" or a "מגו" in American law?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60675/is-there-%d7%a4%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%90%d7%a1%d7%a8-%d7%94%d7%95%d7%90-%d7%a4%d7%94-%d7%a9%d7%94%d7%aa%d7%99%d7%a8-or-a-%d7%9e%d7%92%d7%95-in-american-law) 
[Is one allowed to audio/ video record someone without their knowledge or consent?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99727/is-one-allowed-to-audio-video-record-someone-without-their-knowledge-or-consent?r=SearchResults&s=6|29.7885) 
[Substituting security deposit for final month's rent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/substituting-security-deposit-for-final-months-rent?r=SearchResults&s=8|28.3738) 
etc.

Comment: Seems off topic to me

Comment: Since we're talking about common law jurisdiction, how would you define American law? What should be done with federal law?

Comment: Most voted to close as too broad. I’d like to add that this falls under off-topic as comparative religion, as it requires outside knowledge of something that’s unreasonable to expect the average participant on here to know.